# Do you need to call mysqli_stmt::close before you call mysqli::close?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm not exactly sure why [mysqli_stmt::close](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) is needed. Is it enough to just call [mysqli::close](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)?

Is it needed only when you want to execut multiple prepared statements? Or is it also needed if you execute just one?

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to read all the results from a particular statement. In such a case, you should close it so the next query can be run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the nature of your script.

If it's a regular web-page, that runs for a fraction of second, neither stmt::close nor mysqli::close is ever needed - PHP will close all the resources automatically.

While in a long-running PHP script it's good to close particular statements when you don't need them anymore, as every statement allocates some resources on the server that otherwise can be used by other connections.

Comment: Does the second prepared statement work if i don't close the first one? So `mysqli_stmt::close` it's just a resource deallocation thing?

Comment: @JoSmo it depends on whether you fetched all the rows from the first query or not. Either way, to control this behavior you have to use get_result/store_result methods, it's a civilized way to handle the situation. while a statement closure is rather a barbaric way.

Answer (score 2):

Normally one doesn't need to close any database connections, or most other connections in PHP. As the garbage handler and the associated cleanup code does this automatically.

However, as noted in the comment by @Phil, sometimes you might want to close something earlier. Most common situations are either by not wanting the entire resultset, should a specific condition occur and you need to run another prepared statement; Or when you need to conserve resources.

Of these two the former is by far the most common, and even that isn't really common. So most of the time you do not need to worry about this.

Also, I recommend using the PDO library. It has a few more features than MySQLi, and a few other advantages over the older MySQLi-library.

Comment: Care to provide a non-artificial example of such a "condition" when you throw away the result you just selected from a DB?

Comment: @YourCommonSense judging from past PHP/MySQL questions, it seems to be the way most developers check if a record exists ;)

Comment: @Phil you don't need to close a statement after that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of such a situation at the moment, as I said; Quite rate. The closest I can get to is when you've retrieved a set of data from the database to do some calculations on, until you hit a certain limit. And once that limit is hit you want to update the data, requiring you to discard the remainder of the previous data in order to do so.

Comment: @ChristianF 1. you should always make a database to do calculations for you. 2. So you have to do with limits as well - choose your limit beforehand, by setting it in a query. In fact, selecting more rows than you need is a severe bug, a design flaw. You should never allow such a situation in the first place. This behavior can make your server die even before you will call close.

Comment: Note that I said that this wasn't exactly common, so I'm well aware of the fact that you normally only want to select what you need. However, some times complex business rules makes it impossible to determine exactly how much you need. While most simple calculations should be done in the DB if possible, implementing complex business rules in the DB is also (usually) not a good idea. Not only because it can make things a lot more complex to understand, but also due to speed/resource concerns. Programming languages are generally more optimized for such than DB-engines.

Comment: About PDO/MySQLi, i'm using PDO normally, but the web app on which i'm working now is using MySQLi everywhere and it would be too much work to change it everywhere. So far i miss only 2 things in MySQLi, named parameters and binding parameters with an array. Everything else looks almost the same so far. :) I guess that i won't be closing anything anymore if it's not really needed (multiple prepared statements or resource heavy scripts).

Comment: @JoSmo in fact PDO has [a lot of other benefits](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#array).

Comment: Great link @YourCommonSense. Thanks! :)